# SFML draw many sprites

Tags: c++, sfml

So I need to draw one sprite like 5 times, moving another sprite some pixels forward, so they don't stack. My for loop didn't work and now I have no idea how to do this. I also created a class Hero, because I need to draw it's sprite only 1 time. When I run the program, it displays only 1 tower on nothing.

```
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow screen(sf::VideoMode(700, 580), "SFML Demo");
    sf::Event event;
    int posX = 0, posY = 0;
    Image TileSet;
    TileSet.loadFromFile("Town.png");
    Hero My_Hero("Orc.png");
    Texture TowerTexture;
    TowerTexture.loadFromImage(TileSet);
    Sprite Tower;
    Tower.setTexture(TowerTexture);
    Tower.setPosition(0, 0);
    Tower.setTextureRect(IntRect(383, 96, 145, 280));


    while (screen.isOpen()) {
        while (screen.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
                screen.close();
        }

        screen.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            screen.draw(Tower);
            posX += 40;
            Tower.setPosition(posX, posY);
        }
        My_Hero.MoveHero();
        screen.draw(My_Hero.getSprite());
        screen.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explained what exactly is not working and how do you know it doesn't.

Comment: changed it, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from `posX`.
You should set back posX to zero every frame.

Something like:

```
posX = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    screen.draw(Tower);
    posX += 40;
    Tower.setPosition(posX, posY);
}
```